# COMO IDENTIFICAR NOMES DENTRO DE UM NOME NO MESMO ARQUIVO? PYTHON

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, arquivo, glob

Aí galera, estou com uma dúvida em python e queria saber se vocês poderiam me ajudar, estou querendo automatizar meu trabalho de forma eficaz

Beleza, há duas pastas com inúmeras planilhas excel. Nessas pastas, há excels com os nomes:

"DIA_TipoDeTeste_NomeDoTeste_NomeDoProjeto"

Há vários nomes de projeto para o mesmo tipo de teste, e há vários  tipos de teste para o mesmo nome de projeto

Minha dúvida é:
Tem como dividir os projetos entre "NomeDoTeste", "NomeDoProjeto e etc usando alguma função? Que função eu uso pra definir qual teste é qual? (Tipo, saber qual o nome do projeto do teste, o tipo e o nome do teste) para poder compará-lo com a outra pasta?

Vou tentar explicar de forma melhor. Na pasta 1 há os testes 01.01.2022_TesteRápido_Teste1_ProjetoAlfa, 01.01.2022_TesteRápido_Teste2_ProjetoAlfa, 01.01.2022_TesteLento_Teste1_ProjetoBeta

Eu quero falar que - Se tiver "Teste1" no nome, faça uma operação X na pasta 2, Se tiver "TesteRápido" no nome, faça uma operação Y na pasta 2

Basicamente eu só quero dividir os nomes dos testes para que eu possa identificar o tipo de projeto feito e etc em cada um dos arquivos excel

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Poste um exemplo reproduzível do que está fazendo e onde está tendo problemas. 

Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma função loop para verificar os nomes dos arquivos, e dentro adicionar o recurso `split()`. O `split` faz a separação de uma string por algum caractere definido pelo usuário. Por exemplo

```
nomes = "João Paulo/Maria Paula/Ana Beatriz/José Pedro"
print(nomes.split('/'))
#resultado: ['João Paulo', 'Maria Paula', 'Ana Beatriz', 'José Pedro']
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era isso que eu estava querendo! Me ajudou mt!